# Interactive filtering data table in Plotly by using a dropdown

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, dropdown, plotly-python

I am trying to make an interactive table where the values of the table change by selecting a value from a dropdown. This should be done only in Plotly (not Dash) as I need to share the file with other users.

For example:

If I chose Channel_1 then the tabel should be

| Date | A_item | B_item | C_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-27 | 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2020-02-27 | 8 | 7 | 2 |

If I chose Channel_2 then the tabel should be

| Date | A_item | B_item | C_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-27 | 0 | 10 | 9 |

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2020-01-27","2020-02-27","2020-03-27"],
                   "A_item":[2, 8, 0],
                   "B_item":[1, 7, 10],
                   "C_item":[9, 2, 9],
                   "Channel_type":["Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_2"]
                   })

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=items,
        font=dict(size=10),
        align="left"
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=..... ,
        align = "left")
    ))

updatemenu= []
buttons=[]
for channel in df['Channel_type'].unique():
    buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label=channel,
                        args=[{.....}])
                  )

updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()

updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenu)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

- you can modify contents of figures.  For the use case you note it's modify **cells** contents
- **updatemenus** is static, so it's multiple static views onto the dataframe
- code below

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2020-01-27", "2020-02-27", "2020-03-27"],
        "A_item": [2, 8, 0],
        "B_item": [1, 7, 10],
        "C_item": [9, 2, 9],
        "Channel_type": ["Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_2"],
    }
)

fig = go.Figure(go.Table(header={"values": df.columns}, cells={"values": df.T.values}))
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "cells": {
                                "values": df.T.values
                                if c == "All"
                                else df.loc[df["Channel_type"].eq(c)].T.values
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for c in ["All"] + df["Channel_type"].unique().tolist()
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

[image]

#### multiple menus

Make **updatemenus** list a *list comprehension*

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2020-01-27", "2020-02-27", "2020-03-27"],
        "A_item": [2, 8, 0],
        "B_item": [1, 7, 10],
        "C_item": [9, 2, 9],
        "Channel_type": ["Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_2"],
    }
)

fig = go.Figure(go.Table(header={"values": df.columns}, cells={"values": df.T.values}))
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "y": 1 - (i / 5),
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "cells": {
                                "values": df.T.values
                                if c == "All"
                                else df.loc[df[menu].eq(c)].T.values
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for c in ["All"] + df[menu].unique().tolist()
            ],
        }
        for i, menu in enumerate(["Channel_type", "Date"])
    ]
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a second dropdown as an additional criterium let's say Date?

Comment: updated - **updatemenus** is a list so construct it with a list comprehension

Comment: That was  a great answer, and helped me a lot with a visual I am building.  Just a little detail, add the pandas to your import, is obvious but perhaps not so much for the python new guy  that wants to use your solution.

Comment: The multiple dropdown section is broken. It does not apply the `and` condition to both filters. Either one or the other filter is active which defeats the purpose of having multiple dropdowns.