# python / pandas html interface for exploring multilevel data-set?

Tags: python, html, pandas

Working in Python, I have a pandas DataFrame df. The DataFrame df comes from a groubpy and hence has multilevel columns. df has a hundred groups (index), a dozen base columns (level 0) and a dozen agregation function (level 1) which is a bit tedious to go trough.

I'd like a more interactive way to explore the agregated DataFrame by level (0 or 1). That is I'd like an html display that would allow to select a value for level 0 or 1 and show the df filtered on this level. Is there and easy way to do that ?

Yes i could code the filter myself, but the goal of this is to provide non-coding user a way to explore the data in an html report.

Answer (score 1):

You can try plotly tables and save it as html file. Here is an example: [Interactive filtering data table in Plotly by using a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568250/interactive-filtering-data-table-in-plotly-by-using-a-dropdown).

Comment: Please refrain from posting link only answers. Links might not work in the future. Please [edit] your answer to include the most relevant informations